# RVM does not change gemset upon entering directory

Tags: ruby, rvm, ruby-1.9.3

I am facing an issue with RVM.

The issue is, when I go into a directory - for example `cucumber` - RVM does not switch to the gemset that is set in the local Gemfile.

Gemfile is as follows:

> ruby '1.9.3'
>   #ruby-gemset=cucumber

Output of `rvm gemset list_all`:

```
> gemsets for ruby-2.0.0-p247 (found in /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247)
> => (default)        
>    global
>    test
>
> gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p0 (found in /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0)
> => (default)        
>    cucumber
>    global
```

Output of `type rvm | head -1` :

```
> rvm is a function
```

`source /home/kenny/.rvm/scripts/rvm` is present in `~/.bash_profile`

RVM version: `rvm 1.23.14 (master)`

Tested with setting `rvm current 2.0.0@test`, than going in to the directory but the gemset did not change.

Tried sourcing the rvm script directly as well, but did not work.

So the question is, why is it not working?

Any feedback is welcome.

Comment: Have you set up an `rvmrc` file?  http://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc  Or any RVM project-specific files?  http://rvm.io/workflow/projects

Comment: No, RVM install is fresh. Only modification was to install the 2 ruby versions and create the gemsets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to create a project (or directory) specific file per these docs:  http://rvm.io/workflow/projects  Those will change your ruby version and gemset upon entering the directory where that file is located.

Comment: Strange, Gemfile was set with `ruby '1.9.3'` when I set it to `ruby "1.9.3"` did not do the trick, but setting `#ruby=1.9.3` works.